# My question has suddenly lost all its comments?

Tags: support, comments

So I was looking at my recently posted [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/the-mathematics-club), and noticed that all the comments on the question itself have gone missing.

Is this something that's only on my side or do other also not see the comments?

Most of the things listed under the "Stuff from comments" section in the question came from comments that were made on the question itself.

For clarification, I'm not angry at this, just confused. There were 20+ comments and now they've vanished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted 'em.

There were a heck of a lot of comments there (30 or so?), and it looked like you'd edited the important information into your question, making the comments obsolete.

There were a lot of comments to sort through, though, and cross-referencing each comment chain is a long and tedious process, so if you think I might have missed an important comment, let me know and I'd be happy take a look.

Comment: Ah OK. No I got the "hints" that I had posted in there. I was mostly confused where they had gone.